# android 4.0.3 ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT intent not working

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When i try to use this Intent like so....

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(i,INSERT_CONTACT);
```

it loads the contact list then after selecting or creating a contact I do not return back to my app. i have checked the logs and nothing stands out. Is there a new intent action in ICS?

Thanks

Comment: nobody is having this problem?

Comment: I have a related problem, made another question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597080/add-contact-intent-doesnt-return-data-onactivityresult-under-ics

Comment: I went with just building my own picker / editor which uses 
    ---- Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); ----
and then allows user to edit information within my own custom activity . :( wish it was native

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551821/android-4-0-3-and-finish-activity - similar issue and no reply

Comment: Partial answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597080/add-contact-intent-doesnt-return-data-onactivityresult-under-ics/9885132#9885132

Answer (score 1):

Your missing this line:

```
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Larry Page");
```

**Valid "fields"**:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html