# Incorrect navigation while contact saving on Android

Tags: android, save, edit, contacts, android-4.4-kitkat

Although the documentation says that this bug is fixed (see: [Add the navigation flag](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html#InsertEdit)), I am experiencing the same problem.

From my application I want to add new Android contact, and after the saving is completed I want to get back to my application (the activity that called the insert new android contact intent). That's why I am using:

```
i.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
```

Adding this line, I get the expected behaviour on some phones, and others just behave differently (the user is not navigated back to my application).

I have experienced this problems on Sony Xperia Z, Sony Xperia Z2 and LG G2 mini, all running on 4.4.2, and also LG G3 and Sony Z2 running Lollipop.

Does someone know what is the problem here, and if something has changed.

The saving works properly on for example HTC M8 with 4.4.3 and Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Lollipop.

Nevertheless, if someone knows a solution, please please share. Thx

Comment: The same thing happens on LG G3 running Android Lollipop. Have someone found a solution for this? Please share

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I'm having the same issue on Xperia E3 4.4

Comment: No, I did not unfortunately.