# Android 4.0.3 and finish activity

Tags: android, logging, android-intent, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, phone-call

I have and Activity A calling Activity B. Then Activity B dials a number and
then on the `IDLE-OFFHOOK- IDLE` state I call `ActivityB.this.finish()` so
that activity A shows on front.

This all worked fine from Android 2.3.x till version 4.0.

Now it doesn't work on android 4.0.3 emulator and 4.0.2. Why?

Can someone help?

Comment: "doenst work" is a useless statement.

Comment: Just a guess but try this.finish() only. Anyhow a little insight into your code would be nice. And as mentioned a clear description.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you have overridden `onDestroy` method and it is falling over because of an Exception (only occurring in 4.0), which is preventing the Activity from closing properly. Also just try to invoke `finish()` simply on Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution for this case is to use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

You can switch activity from A to B, in activity B do your work and handle results in activity A at override method `onActivityResult()`.